# force website display mobile view version even on desktop version?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, grid

I was created mobile first website using bootstrap. but I want to displaying this site on desktop version still in mobile view. When I set body style with max-with = 600px my the display very bad. because I was created many col for lg media. 
for example:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col col-lg-3"> -> I was create something like this in many page
   <div>
</div>
```

So, When I set body style with max-with = 600px. it still display as col-lg-3. And I want the display still in col / col-12 without change every single class on every page. because someday I will built the desktop version.

Anyone know, what the simple way to make my site display mobile version on desktop?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Dev tools allow to simulate a mobile device in F12 then the top-left side of the dev tools, if that is what you are looking for. Otherwise i would try to control the 'window' element size.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Comment: No I won't jus for simulate only but for live website. with body control still showing 4 column div. thanks Rune

Answer (score 0):

Parent elements

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-3">
    child elements goes here --
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes...but actually I won't to change the code. so I just need something like frame with width maybe 600px in every page on my website. thanks @PiedPiper

Comment: You can always go to developers option in chrome to test your work.

Comment: Okay PiedPiper, but I need not only for test but for existing running web on the internet